# Cannot convert value of type '[array]' to expected argument type 'Range<Int>'

Tags: swift, foreach, swiftui

I can not understand what could be the problem

i have some Json 
for example is

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Title",
    "info": "info",
    "brand": "brand",
    "model": "MODEL",
    "make_year": year,
    "properties": [
        {
                "id": 1,
                "icon": "ic_rgb",
                "label": "color",
                "value": "red"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "icon": "ic_car",
                "label": "type",
                "value": "value"
            },
            {   "id": 3,
                "icon": "ic_fuel",
                "label": "fuel",
                "value": "gas"
            }  
        ],
    },
{
    "id": 2,
    "title": "title2",
    "message": "massage2",
    "info": "wow you are amazing, thanks for the help",
    "properties": [
        {
                "id": 11,
                "icon": "ic_rgb",
                "label": "2color",
                "value": "2blue"
            },
            {
                "id": 21,
                "icon": "ic_car",
                "label": "2type",
                "value": "2cgh"
            },
            {   "id": 31,
                "icon": "ic_fuel",
                "label": "fuel",
                "value": "test"
            },
            ....
        ],
}
]
```

and my model

```
struct Unicards: Hashable, Codable, Identifiable {
var id: Int
var title: String?
var info: String?
var brand: String?
var model: String?
var make_year: Int?
var messege: String?
var messege_color: String?
var price: String?
var price_currency: String?
var price_tooltip: String?


var properties: [HPropert]?
struct HPropert: Hashable, Codable, Identifiable {

    var id: Int
    var icon: String?
    var label: String
    var value: String

}
```

and what the problem... i'm trying to create forEach method for horizontal collection for properties

I partially succeeded, I implemented this method with a nested array, and it even generates the number of cells correctly. wow!)

but when I want to assign values ​​for the text by index it gives an error ...

I actually can not understand the problem, since the array has already been calculated and created by the number of cell objects.

but when I ask the formula to assign values ​​I get

```
Cannot convert value of type '[Unicards.HPropert]' to expected argument type 'Range<Int>'
```

my code below

```
struct Card_cell_rowOfCheracteristics: View {

var data2: Unicards

var body: some View {
    let properties = data2.properties!

    return    VStack() {
//            Text("thanx bro!. have a nice day")
//                .font(.system(size: 14))
//                .font(.headline)
//                .fontWeight(.light)
//                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)

        ScrollView(Axis.Set.horizontal) {



            HStack {


                ForEach(properties) { card in <--- Cannot convert value of type '[Unicards.HPropert]' to expected argument type 'Range<Int>'
                    VStack {
                        Image()
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .frame(width: 34, height: 34)


                        VStack {

                            Text(properties[card].label) 
                                .font(.system(size: 14))
                                .fontWeight(.medium)
                            Text(properties[card].value)
                                .font(.system(size: 14))
                        }


                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}

struct Card_cell_rowOfCheracteristics_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Card_cell_rowOfCheracteristics(data2: PlatesData[0])
    }
}
}
```

but if i say

```
properties[0].label
```

no errors occur

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try doing something like this:

```
ForEach(properties) { card in
    .
    Text(card?.label) 
    .
}
```

I think the issue is that each element in the array s referred as a `card` when you are iterating through the array. So to get the properties of that element in the array you would do so by: `card?.[property_name]`

Comment: You are absolutely right! 

    ForEach(properties, id: \.self)    , its not work and makes more mistakes   but! Text(card?.label)
this is exactly what I missed, thank you very much

Answer (score 15):

This error indicates your `data2.properties!`'s type does not conform to the `Identifiable` protocol.
Say, if your `data2.properties!`'s type is A, then try to do:

```
struct A: Identifiable {
    ...
    var id: String {
        return /*some ID*/
    }
    ...
}
```

This should fix your problem "behind the hood".

Answer (score 2):

As @UndergroundFox pointed, one way of solving this is conforming to `Identifiable` protocol. Another is to specify in the `ForEach` one key to serve as unique identifier, in my case I used a date that I know is unique (because I have one entry per day):

```
ForEach(arPictures,  id: \.date) { picture in
```